# Join same table to multiple fields

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have this SQL and i am trying to join a table of people's login names to a table of tasks that contains several user ids

```
  SELECT Task.TaskID
      ,Project.Project
      ,Task.Task
      ,Task.Description
      ,Task.OwnerLoginID //shown as Login.UserName
      ,Task.SubmitterID //shown as Login.UserName
      ,Task.IsVisible
  FROM Task
  INNER JOIN Project ON Task.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID
  /*
  INNER JOIN Login ON Task.SubmitterID = Login.LoginID
  INNER JOIN Login ON Task.OwnerLoginID = Login.LoginID
  */
  WHERE IsVisible = 1
```

i get an error in the commented out lines at the bottom where am i going wrong?

Comment: Please provide the error

Comment: As typed it's impossible to tell which instance of "login" you ever mean.  You need to use aliases so as to avoid that uncertainty.  It should imply this much in your error message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try assigning alias names to the tables e.g.

```
SELECT Task.TaskID
      ,Project.Project
      ,Task.Task
      ,Task.Description
      ,submitted.UserName
      ,owner.UserName
      ,Task.IsVisible
  FROM Task
  INNER JOIN Project ON Task.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID
  INNER JOIN Login submitted ON Task.SubmitterID = submitted.LoginID
  INNER JOIN Login owner ON Task.OwnerLoginID = owner.LoginID
  WHERE IsVisible = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to JOIN the same table means, Give like this

```
  INNER JOIN Login L ON Task.SubmitterID = L.LoginID
  INNER JOIN Login LA ON Task.OwnerLoginID = LA.LoginID
```